# Bijective holomorphic function $f$ from $S:=\{z\in\mathbb{C}\mid 0<\operatorname{Re}(z)<1\}$ to $S$ with $f(0.5)=0.25$

Tags: complex-analysis

I have to find a function $f: S\to S$ with $S:=\{z\in\mathbb{C}\mid 0<\operatorname{Re}(z)<1\}$ and the extra condition $f(\frac{1}{2}) = \frac{1}{4}$.

I spend several hours on this already trying some special functions, polynomials or construction a mobius transformation that fulfill my conditions, but nothing really worked.

I am not asking for a entire solution to this problem, but can anyone give me a hint? How am I supposed to approach such exercises?

Comment: Try the exponential function on $0<Im(z)<2\pi$. The first step should be a bijective holomorphic function $g:\mathbb{D}\to S$, $\mathbb{D}$ denotes the open unit disc. Then you search for an equivalent function $h:\mathbb{D}\to\mathbb{D}$.

Comment: @TomTom314  thank you, but how should i find a bijective holomorphic function between $\mathbb{D}$ and $S$?

Comment: The is a mistake in my comment $2\pi$ should be $\pi$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find a bijective holomorphic function $f:S\to S$ we construct a bijective holomorphic function $g:S\to\mathbb{D}$ and then solve an equivalent problem for $h:\mathbb{D}\to \mathbb{D}$.

The construction of $g$. Basically we compose several bijective functions $S\to T\xrightarrow{\exp} U\to \mathbb{D}$. For the map $T\xrightarrow{\exp} U$ we define $T:=\{z\in\mathbb{C}\mid 0<\operatorname{Im}(z)< \pi\}$. The definition of $U$ and the other maps I'll fill in later if needed.

Comment: So from $S$ to $T$, I would just rotate the $S$ with $i$ and scale it with $2\pi$. If I use the exponential function I get $U=\{z\in\mathbb{C}\mid Re(z)>0\}$. All I need is to find a function that maps $U$ to $\mathbb{D}$. Then I can apply $\sqrt z$ on $\mathbb{D}$ and invert every step I did before, right?

Comment: Almost, the bijektive holomorphic map $\mathbb{D}\to\mathbb{D}$ are given by some möbius transformations, $\sqrt{z}$ has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Then I would chose the map from $U$ to $\mathbb{D}$ as the inverse of $\frac{1+z}{1-z}$. But why would $\sqrt z$ doesnt work as map from $\mathbb{D}$ to $\mathbb{D}$?

Comment: first there is no holomorphic extension at 0, second it's not bijective because of $(-z)^2=z^2$.

Comment: So I found $\frac{-0.5z}{z-1.5}$ as mobius transformation for $\mathbb{D}$, would this work out?

Comment: I doubt it. Once you have $g$ you want to look for an automorphism $h$ such that $h(g(1/2)) = g(1/4)$. Further the möbius transformation doesn't map $\mathbb{D}$ to $\mathbb{D}$ (I'm fairly sure).

Comment: Well, I solved a equation system for a,b,c,d to find a tranformation with f(1)=1, f(0)=0 and f(0.5)=0.25, and this is one of infinitely many solutions. Since it maps circles on circles, this should work out I thought

Comment: Ok, I already got a warning about extended discussions. At this point I would recommend some reading on möbius transformations. For example a chapter in Remmert, Funktionentheorie or Needham, Visual complex analysis.